# How do I access the global market in SimCity?

Tags: simcity-2013

I'm unable to find any real documentation if this feature is even released yet as part of SimCity 2013.

Is there a way to access the global market within SimCity World? Apart from just selling commodities though my trade depot I was under the impression there was a way to do analysis and look at trends in market prices.

When I go to SimCity World I only have Leaderboards and Challenges. At least one of my cities in the region has a Trade HQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global market tab was originally designed to be a part of the Sim City World window next to the "Leaderboards" and "Challenges" tabs but it was removed before release of the game.

Here is a pre-release version of the window:

[image: here]

Currently it appears that prices of goods do not fluctuate on the global market although on release day the prices were fluctuating seemingly randomly so it is likely a feature Maxis is tweaking to reduce server load.

Comment: So I guess it's pretty difficult to see the pricing trend of a particular commodity since this window is removed? Right now oil is around 4.5k per 1k of barrels so getting the daily 160k of petroleum commerce is a task in itself.

Comment: @Matthew you are correct. As far as I know, theres currently no way to see the trends.

Comment: Yes, at the moment there are no trends.
Oil is §4,500 / 1000 barrels, Alloy is §48,375 / 10 tons, and Plastic is §12,003 / 1k crates